# Normalising extreme items within datasets

Tags: dataset, standard-deviation, normalization, weights

I have a a dataset where each item is a % above or below 100% (taking an individual item, dividing by the mean). In order to produce a rank I weighted each item by a % (summing to 100%) to provide a master weighting. The problem I have is that within each individual dataset, the % +/- is very different. E.g. the min/max for one set of data is 200%, and in another it's 20% (due to the similarity of the original data). Therefore when I apply my subjective weighting, those with extreme deviation from the mean are effectively a larger component of the master weighting.

At the moment I am using Standard Deviation to sensitize my percentage weighting. I was wondering if there was a better way to essentially put each data item on a level playing field

Thanks a lot, in advance, for your help

Stephen

Comment: Can you provide a small example dataset to illustrate this?

Answer (score 0):

You could provide a scaling variable for each individual dataset.  Or, you could analyze the log of the deviations.